# Can't run Apache - Would having Ruby on Rails and mysql server installed on the same machine be the reason why?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, mysql5.5

everyone. I am trying unsuccessfully to run Apache on my machine. I used the command line to find out all the applications that are using port 80 and I ended them, but Apache refuses to run on my server after that. I have a Ruby on Rails web service and mySQL server 5.5 installed on the same machine. Could that be the reason why Apache won't run on my machine?

Comment: Probably not.  What do your apache error logs say?

Comment: How are you running Rails? Passenger, Mongrel, CGI, FastCGI, mod_ruby?

Comment: Temporarily set apache to listen on a high port like 8080 or 7080.  If it starts, stop it and set it to listen on 82. If is starts (you are starting it up as root when you're configured to listen on a port number below 1024?).  If it starts while listening on 82 and it starts when running on 7080, then something is using port 80.   Of course, the easiest way to tell if something is listening on port 80 is to telnet to it, type " GET / HTTP/1.1 " and press enter a couple of times.  You'll probably see the server type in the response header.

Comment: @mahnsc - how do I set apache to listen on another port?

Comment: Edit the httpd.conf.  look for a "Listen 80" directive.  Change 80 to 7080.  Restart apache.  Do you run apache as a user like www or do you run it using sudo?  If you're running on a port >1024, then you don't need to use sudo to start it.

Comment: @mahnsc - Thanks, I changed it, but a pop-up box still comes up saying "Apache HTTP Server has stopped working. Windows is looking for a solution to the problem...". I'm running  apache as a user like www. Any suggestions as to why I'm still getting problems?

Comment: If you don't need it, you could unload PHP support.  Comment out any php related modules.  This is just a guess, though.

Comment: @mahnsc -I need the PHP support unfortunately...are there any other reasons as to why Apache won't work?

Comment: There were patches available for a php/pdo issue on windows.  Could be this but the article is a couple years old: http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=32617  Does anything get written to your apache error log when you try to start it up?

Comment: @mahnsc - No, nothing gets written to my error log file... in fact, when I use UniController to start it up, it will say that the server is running even though Apache still crashes...

Answer (score 0):

Use   **netstat -a | find "80"** to find out what app is binding to port 80.  It's most likely a web server (e.g. IIS)